# Creating an object inside an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, constructor, scope

I'm trying to make a simple program for a bank account. I have created a class called Bank to make and instance and in the main class, where the main method is, I have made an if statement which will create an instance of the class "Bank" depending on the conditions met. The problem is that I can use the instance methods, which is outside the if statement. I have created two constructors for the object class, one with a constructor method parameter and another method which doesnt take any parameters, which is the reason of using an if statement.

```
 public static void start() {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Welcome to your banking app!");
      System.out.println("What is your initial balance, enter below. If none enter : n");
      String choice = scanner.nextLine();

      if(choice.equals("n")){
           Bank account1 = new Bank();
      }
      else{
           System.out.println("Enter your initial balance :");
           double ibalance = scanner.nextDouble();
           Bank account1 = new Bank(ibalance);
      }

      System.out.println("Enter 1 to see balance Enter 2 to withdraw  Enter 3 to deposit money Enter 4 to close account Enter 5 to exit");
      choice = scanner.nextLine();
      double amount = 0.0; 
      if(choice.equals("1")){
           System.out.println("Balance is :" + account1.getBalance());
      }

      else if(choice.equals("2")){
           System.out.println("Enter the amount to withdraw");
           amount = scanner.nextInt();
           account1.withdraw(amount);
      }

      else if(choice.equals("3")){
           System.out.println("Enter the amount to deposit");
           amount = scanner.nextInt();
           account1.deposit(amount);
      }

      else if(choice.equals("4")){
           account1.close();
      }

      else if(choice.equals("5")){
           System.exit(0);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

your Bank object will only live in if clause. should change to :

```
Bank account1 = null;
if (clause){
    account1 = new Bank();
}else{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

declare the Bank object outside of the if else scope, so you can access to it later, initialize that to **null** and assign a reference to a new instance of `Bank` depending on the condition if-else

```
Bank account1 = null;
if(choice.equals("n")){
    account1 = new Bank();
} else{
    System.out.println("Enter your initial balance :");
    double ibalance = scanner.nextDouble();
    account1 = new Bank(ibalance);
}
```

Comment: *optionally* initialize it to null. That's entirely personal preference.

Comment: Since `account1` is initialized in both `if` and `else` you do not need to assign it to `null`

Comment: Thank you!! Got no compiler or syntax errors now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the **Bank** class that is not initialised. Then initialise it where needed. Note that the account1 variable is created outside of your nested conditional statements.

```
   Bank account1;

   if(choice.equals("n"))
      account1 = new Bank();
   else
   {
       System.out.println("Enter your initial balance :");
       double ibalance = scanner.nextDouble();
       account1 = new Bank(ibalance);
   }
```

You want to reuse the account1 variable as much as you can in this instance instead of creating new instances.

Comment: @Michael i see that now, i looked at it quickly and assumed it was his whole class.

Comment: Alright. By the way, you shouldn't an if statement without braces.

Comment: @Michael i would say its personal preference, if its just one line i usually don't use braces. but again personal preference. It should compile either way.

Comment: Somewhat. The general consensus is using braces is less error prone. A one line `if (true) foo();` is okay, but your mixing of styles is just confusing.

Comment: @Michael what do you mean 'mixing of styles is just confusing'? there are multiple lines in the else condition. How else would it compile?

Comment: If someone added a line under `account1 = new Bank()` then at a glance it might look valid even though its not. Adding the braces to the first block removes this possibility.

Comment: If someone added a line under account1 = new Bank() then it would not compile... im still not sure why that bothers you so much...

Comment: Sure. But if there were no else block it *would* compile. [The consensus](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16530/253987), and I agree, is that your way is worse. But it doesn't bother me. You can do whatever you like.